# PHP is surrounding the entire script in a try catch block a bad idea?

Tags: php

On [this page of the PHP docs](http://php.net/exceptions), the first comment suggests a solution to custom error handling.

Johan writes:

> Custom error handling on entire pages can avoid half rendered pages
>   for the users:

```
<?php
ob_start();
try {
    /*contains all page logic 
    and throws error if needed*/
    ...
} catch (Exception $e) {
  ob_end_clean();
  displayErrorPage($e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

I was already going to use output buffering to avoid the half-render issue, but I hadn't thought of the possibility of surrounding the page render region in a big try/catch block.

In fact coming from a Java world, this kind of practice is more or less considered bad. But I know PHP and Java differ greatly so I'll ask here...

Is the practice above bad in any way (and obviously WHY is it bad)? Thanks!

Comment: The thing is, much of PHP will never throw a catchable exception.  PHP's errors (E_ERROR, E_WARNING, E_NOTICE, etc) are not exceptions and a `try/catch` won't catch them. If you are explicitly throwing an exception, or using a library which will throw one, you can try/catch around it but the "half-rendered page" referenced in the docs is usually due to a PHP fatal error, which _isn't an exception_.

Comment: Any way to mend this behavior?

Comment: The docs [suggest a custom error handler with ErrorException](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php). I've admittedly never used this...

Comment: That could work, call the same or similar function on traditional errors as you do with exceptions.

Comment: Seems like a way to chew up a lot of memory space if you are going to always use an output buffer.